# Android Canvas - How to use Path.quadto to draw up inverse curve?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm using the Path.quadto function to draw a curve.

> public void quadTo(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
>           isSimplePath = false;
>           native_quadTo(mNativePath, x1, y1, x2, y2);
>       }

```
    path.rQuadTo(50, 50, 100, 0);
    canvas.drawPath(path, p);
```

I got it to draw exactly what I wanted, but it's upside down. How do I flip it vertically 180 degrees?
(It's a smiley face, right now, need it to be a sad face)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the documentation a little closer, I saw this:

> Parameters
>
> dx1   The amount to add to the x-coordinate of the last point on this
>   contour, for the control point of a quadratic curve
>
> dy1   The amount to add to the y-coordinate of the last point on this
>   contour, for the control point of a quadratic curve
>
> dx2   The amount to add to the x-coordinate of the last point on this
>   contour, for the end point of a quadratic curve
>
> dy2   The amount to add to the y-coordinate of the last point on this
>   contour, for the end point of a quadratic curve

According to this, the dy1 component is the most important for this situation. By descreasing this to a negative number, I was able to change the arc to be concave down.

public void rQuadTo (float dx1, float **dy1**, float dx2, float dy2)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you start to draw at (0,0), just set your first point and flip y1 and y2.

```
moveTo(0,50);
path.rQuadTo(50,0,100,50);
```